# Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading error in Anguler2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app which main page is divided into 4 parts(Header, Sidebar, Content and footer).Sidebar have mainmenu component inside of it. My Problem is when I try to add mainmenu to sidebar it gives following error.

Project Folder Structure

[image]

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header';
 import { AppSidebarComponent } from './app-sidebar';
 import { AppContentComponent } from './app-content';
 import { AppFooterComponent } from './app-footer';

 @Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
   directives:[AppHeaderComponent,AppSidebarComponent,AppContentComponent,AppFooterComponent]
 })

 export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
 }
```

app-sidebar.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppMainMenuComponent } from './app-mainmenu';

 @Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'app-sidebar',
   templateUrl: 'app-sidebar.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app-sidebar.component.css'],
   directives:[AppMainMenuComponent]
 })
 export class AppSidebarComponent implements OnInit { 
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {}
 }
```

app-mainmenu.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'app-mainmenu',
   templateUrl: 'app-mainmenu.component.html'
 })

 export class AppMainMenuComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {}
 }
```

Error while reloading

[image]